# Django extended template is not loading base JS at time

Tags: javascript, django

I've in Django 1.11 a base.html which contains all the scripts references.

Then, I've another page.html that extendes base.html with {% extends base.html %} and {% block content %} / {% endblock content %} tags.

Well. In base.html I've a  reference to Chartjs.js plugin. In page.html, if I try to call to Chart() function or just $ jquery, I get "function is not defined". If I open console debugger and try to call $ or just Chart(), it works. So I think that there's a problem with loading time. The page.html is rendered before the js are downloaded or requested!

How can I solve it? I've done it before, I don't know what could be the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: the code of you base.html please !

Comment: Are you sure the js files are requested properly? Check on your server stack the http request code.

Comment: i'm adding base.html code. and yep.
I can call from debugger console those functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your code showing, hard to tell.  Based on what you wrote, perhaps you forgot to put a block and block.super to get the parent (base.html's) Chartjs reference.

This should be in your page.html at the bottom after your {% endblock content %} tag. See example below (using DataTables as example since your code is not shown):

```
</div>

{% endblock content %}
{% block javascript %}
  {{ block.super }}
<script type="application/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#table').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
  });
});
  </script>
{% endblock javascript %}
```

Base.html would have the js section enclosed in

```
{% block javascript %} …. {% endblock javascript %}
```

Comment: really thanks!
i had problems putting the code here in stack overflow.